# Extracting text blocks based on grep output

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, scripting

I'm currently working with a text file that contains the following text blocks:

```
--------------------------------------
Beginning of block
Text
Random Text
keywordA
Text
End of block
--------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
Beginning of block
Text
Random Text
keywordA
Text
End of block
--------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
Beginning of block
Text
Random Text
keywordD
Text
End of block
--------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
Beginning of block
Text
Random Text
keywordd
Text
End of block
--------------------------------------
```

The objective is to have egrep detect certain keywords, and if those words exist, I would like to copy the block to another file. So, I'm currently searching with:

```
if egrep -wi 'keywordA|KeywordB|keywordC' Report
then
        echo "Words found!"

else
        echo "No words found!"
fi
```

I was wondering if there is any way to add a follow up action to use sed (for example) to copy the block of text where the words were found.

Expected output, in this example, would be:

```
--------------------------------------
Beginning of block
Text
Random Text
keywordA
Text
End of block
--------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
Beginning of block
Text
Random Text
keywordA
Text
End of block
--------------------------------------
```

The file "Report" contains dozens of blocks like this, but not all of them have the keyword. I would like to copy just the ones that do *(as demonstrated in the above example)*.

Comment: can you make your sample bigger to include more than one block (incl how they are separated like empty line or only those ---- ) and add expected output for that... `awk` with setting `RS` would be better suited... (also what is your version.. GNU awk, etc)

Comment: am sure this question has a duplicate somewhere... try `awk -v RS= '/keywordA|KeywordB|keywordC/' Report`

Comment: are there always 4 (or 6) lines of text in each block?

Comment: No, the number of lines in each block varies.

Comment: @Sundeep I only run a quick test, but it appears your suggestion worked exactly as expected!! Would you like to submit it as the answer? TY very much!

Answer (score 3):

it's so easy for magic `awk` command:

```
awk -v RS="--------------------------------------"
       '/keywordA/||/keywordB/||/keywordC/' RS='' infile.txt
```

You will get output as like below expected:

```
--------------------------------------
Beginning of block
Text
Random Text
keywordA
Text
End of block
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
Beginning of block
Text
Random Text
keywordA
Text
End of block
--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along those lines will do:

```
awk '
    {
        if(/--------------------------------------/) {
            if(found)
                printf buffer
            buffer = ""
            found = 0
        } else
            buffer = buffer $0 "\n"
    }

    /keyworda|keywordb|whateveryouwant/ {
        found = 1
    }
' input_file.txt
```

Just adjust the keywords in the regexp near the end according to what you need.
I store the lines in a variable, and when I reach a `----…----` line, if I encountered a wanted keyword, I print the content of this variable, then empty it and forget that I found an interesting keyword.
I hope that's what you want. I can still edit it if needed, I guess.

This outputs interesting blocks to the standard output ; redirect the output to a file to copy them.